# Mailing scheduler, API permission check failed; require access CiviCRM

Tags: scheduled-job

Salut.
I am using easycron to trigger cronjobs for civicrm.

- url to call: https://mywebsite.de/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php
- Method: post
- name=cronuser&pass=password&key=key
- cronuser exists as a wordpress user with administator priviledges.
- cronuser exists as a civicrm user, connected to the wordpress user.
- Additionally, cronuser is part of the civicrm group Administrators, which is used in the ACL section to grant priviledges (see images attached) to edit all contacts.
- only mailing scheduler gets this error log message, other tasks are successful when triggered through easycron.
- mailing scheduler works perfect when I trigger it manually, -therefore the problem has to be somewhere in the process of triggering it via url.

I don't understand why I still get the error message (cron log):

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message:
Finished execution of Mailings scheduler with result: Fehler, Error message: API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM

Can this error message NOT be related to user privileges issues, but to some other issues like firewall or folder structure priviledges? (folders leading up to cron.php including the file itself have 755 privileges).

I have tried almost everything, what is there left to test?
Thanks for any hint.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed to cli-Method via Crontab. Since I use Mysql 8 -->
Changed Mysql Auth Method for civicrm Mysql user:

https://dcblog.dev/mysql-80-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client

error: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client The solution is to change the default authentication method to mysql_native_password.

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure cronuser wordpress user has administrator permission or role. It needs most of the Civi permission to run schedule jobs.

Comment: see image attached above. it has administrator role in wordpress.  what else could be the problem?

Comment: Thats not the role i was talking about, you need to go to Users >> Find cronuser user from the users list >> edit the user >> change the role to adminsitrator

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! My wordpress user cronuser does already have the role: administrator (and keymaster).

Comment: I have added one more point: - only mailing scheduler gets this error log message, other tasks are successful when triggered through easycron.

Comment: There was a bug in 2016 and it is batched but the problem seems to be the same: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17968